# Python: How to go one folder back in pathlib

Tags: python, path

After watching my work folder get cluttered I have moved code files corresponding together into a subfolder. The problem is that the data my program uses is itself placed in a subfolder of the now parent folder. I used `pathlib` to extract the data from the subdirectories like so:

```
DATA_DIR = pathlib.Path.cwd().joinpath("Kokam NMC 46 Ah EET","CheckUps",
                                       "Calend_ID{id_nr}_{temp}_{SoC}".format(id_nr = id_nr, temp = temp, SoC = SoC ))
```

where `Kokam NMC 46 Ah EET` is the parent folder to `CheckUps` and so on. Now what I need is to adjust this command in such a way that the path goes back into the parent folder and **then** into `Kokam NMC 46 Ah EET` etc. I had done some research on this site and tried what seemed like a solution in some cases, namely to add `".."`

```
DATA_DIR = pathlib.Path.cwd().joinpath("..","Kokam NMC 46 Ah EET","CheckUps",
                                       "Calend_ID{id_nr}_{temp}_{SoC}".format(id_nr = id_nr, temp = temp, SoC = SoC ))
```

which did not work. Similarly I tried the same strategy for saving a plot

```
plt.savefig('../Graphs/Impedanz Plot von ID{id_nr} NMC{nmc_nr} bei {x} Hertz'.format(id_nr = id_nr, temp = temp, SoC = SoC, nmc_nr = nmc_nr, x=hertz),
                bbox_inches = 'tight', dpi = 600)
```

which returned

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '../Graphs/Impedanz von ID01 NMC46 (bei 35C und 100SOC).png'
```

How does one adjust for backtracking into parent folders using `pathlib`? And if `pathlib` does not have this feature is there another way to do it?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of `..`, do `path.parent`:

```py
>>> pathlib.Path.cwd()
PosixPath('/home/jan/Downloads')
```

```py
>>> pathlib.Path.cwd().parent
PosixPath('/home/jan')
```

For your second attempt, make Python calculate an absolute path from a relative one.

```py
>>> os.path.abspath('../')
'/home/jan'
```

Also make sure the path you are trying to save to is the actually correct path by printing it.